# How to start the previous activity on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My Android app starts an `Activity` when it detects a certain behavior, This behavior reached from some processing in a **non-Activity class**, So I've to start the *desired Activity* from that non_Activity class, and due to that I've to set a `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` Intent flag otherwise I the App will crash, This is the Code for starting the desired Activity from that non_Activity class:

```
Intent menuIntent = new Intent(MyApplication.getAppContext(), Connection.class);
menuIntent.putExtra("EXIT", false);
menuIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
MyApplication.getAppContext().startActivity(menuIntent); // MyApplication.getAppContext() is a class used to get the current context
```

The Activity runs efficiently but when press a cancel button in that Activity the app has to return or restart the last activity before launching this one(whatever this last activity was) but instead of that I got that currently running Activity to reload, And that's my code for returning to the previous Activity:

```
Button cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
       cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 // do some stuff
                 Intent intent = new Intent();
                 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                 startService(intent);
            }
        });
```

And I also tried to just call `finish()` but also didn't work(gives me the same result), also tried to replace `startService(intent);` with `startActivity(intent);` but that made my app crash as intent doesn't contain any Activities.

Comment: Why are you use start service???. And when you use finish() method previous running activity are restarted this is the behavior of android activity life cycle.

Comment: I don't understand your question but if you want to start an Activity, you have to use startActivity... but startActivity needs to be told what to start.  You have to define that in your intent: Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), YourActivity.class);

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

Comment: @mcd that's not happening with me when calling finish at that case.

Comment: @Justin I don't know what's the previous activity

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand what r u trying to achieve . if you finish the current activity previous activity are appear in foreground and onrestart method of previous activity called

Comment: @mcd yea that's what I know about `finish()` method but that's not what I'm getting